# check box checked on page load and show output

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my working code but the only problem is, I want the check box to checked by default and show the jquery output on page load but it only show output when i re-check the check box.

http://jsfiddle.net/pratyush141/2mq5sr1h/

```
$(function() {
$defaultValue = $('.total').val();
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
});

if (total == 0) {
  $('.total').val($defaultValue);
} else {
  $('.total').val('$' + total);
}
});

})


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
<input type="checkbox" checked='checked' value="1" />
<span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="total" value="$90" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just remove the checked=checked from the checkbox, then use jquery to call the click on checkbox

```
<div class="invoice">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>


$(function () {
$defaultValue = $('.total').val();
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function (event) {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
    });

    if (total == 0) {
        $('.total').val($defaultValue);
    } else {
        $('.total').val('$' + total);
    }
});

//Call the click on checkbox
$("input[type=checkbox]").click();
})
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mq5sr1h/5/

Comment: Ok. but not working "jquery-1.8.0.min.js". The page on which, I am going to use above code has "jquery-1.8.0.min.js" and i can't change it, it will disturb another contents

Comment: I change the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2mq5sr1h/5/
Now it can work with jquery 1.8.0 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

You set value of input on click event. You need to set it in `$(document).ready()`. Try to change your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    setValue();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
       setValue();
    });

 });

function setValue()
{
   $defaultValue = $('.total').val();
   var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
    });
   if (total == 0) {
      $('.total').val($defaultValue);
    }
   else {
      $('.total').val('$' + total);
    }
}
```